# The texblock's text doesn't change when i update the property, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

When I check the property manual, with a message box, it shows the new value.
But it doesn't work for the textblock.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7XoV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PropertyChanged` event should be raised when the value of that property is set.

```
class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        field = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

```
class StudentViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _messagee;
    public string Messagee
    {
        get => _messagee;
        set => SetProperty(ref _messagee, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found an easier solution, I just forgot to install the PropertyChanged.Fody package, and that is solved my problem.